# Continue and break statement doing the same thing

Tags: python, maya

This is my 2nd noob question for today... so bear with me. So this is supposed to loop through `'nothing'` and `'persp'` while still renaming/printing `After:[u’concrete_file1’]` because of the `continue;` statement, but I just get empty brackets.  I ran the same function without this:

```
        if not (maya.cmds.ls(texture) and
        maya.cmds.nodeType(texture)=='file'):
            continue;
```

And without  `'nothing'` and `'persp'` and it worked fine so I'm assuming the problem is in there somewhere, but after fiddling with it for a while I still don't know what it is... This'll probably be some super simplistic answer but I'm on day 2 of learning this stuff so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
def process_all_textures(**kwargs):
    pre = kwargs.setdefault('prefix');
    if (isinstance(pre, str) or
    isinstance(pre, unicode)):
        if not pre[-1] == '_':
            pre += '_';
    else: pre = '';
    textures = kwargs.setdefault('texture_nodes');
    new_texture_names = [];
    if (isinstance(textures, list) or
    isinstance(textures, tuple)):
        for texture in textures:
            if not (maya.cmds.ls(texture) and
            maya.cmds.nodeType(texture)=='file'):
                continue;
                new_texture_names.append(
                maya.cmds.rename(
                texture,
                '%s%s'%(pre, texture)
                )
                );
        return new_texture_names;
    else:
        maya.cmds.error('No texture nodes specified');

#Should skip over the 2 invalid objects ('nothing' & 'persp')
#because of the continue statement...

new_textures= [
'nothing',
'persp',
maya.cmds.shadingNode('file', asTexture=True)
];
print ('Before: %s'%new_textures);
new_textures = process_all_textures(
texture_nodes = new_textures,
prefix = 'concrete_'
);
print ('After: %s'%new_textures);

Before: ['nothing', 'persp', u'file1']
After: []
```

Also I'm just using the Maya Script Editor to write all this, is there a better editor that might be easier?

Comment: If you know what the arguments to your function can be (`prefix`, `texture_nodes`, etc), I don't see the advantage of using **kwargs and `dict.setdefault`) and not just something like `process_all_textures(prefix=None, texture_nodes=None)` -- `dict.setdefault` without a second argument does exactly that.

Comment: idk I'm just following a book right now since I'm new to this and they used **kwargs.  It's leading up to a short Python tool so maybe its more for later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include an `else` to make the statements after `continue;` run when `if not (maya.cmds.ls(texture) and maya.cmds.nodeType(texture)=='file'):` is not true.

What happens here, is that there is only that one condition. Whenever that is true, it evaluates `continue;` and skips the rest of the statements. However, whenever that is not true, it *also* skips `new_texture_names.append(maya.cmds.rename(texture, '%s%s'%(pre, texture)));` because that is inside the `if` condition.